# Whole disk encryption with a Windows only Bootcamp

Tags: mac, hard-drive, bootcamp, windows, encryption

I've purchased myself a Mac Book Pro Retina (Haswell) and after giving Mac OS a fair shake have decided to go full Windows 7 and Bootcamp. There is no Mac OS install left on this system.

I am now looking for a way to encrypt my entire hard drive. My requirements are simple:

- AES based whole disk encryption (to take advantage of AES-NI)
- Ability to boot by just entering a password

I've looked at the following:

- **Truecrypt** is a no-go because it is not recommended for use with SSDs
- **Bitlocker** is a no-go because there is no TPM in this system and I
  don't want to haul around a USB thumb drive with me every time I have
  to boot.
- **Symantec Whole Disk Encryption** appears to meet all of my requirements

Before I drop $100 on Symantec I figured I'd ask the exerts if there is any other software out there I can use. I prefer Open Source but understand that might not be possible.

Comment: After re-reading the following:

http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/wear-leveling

and

http://www.truecrypt.org/docs/trim-operation

I've decided that I'm willing to take the small(ish) risks involved with using Truecrypt on a SSD.

My goal is to prevent the average chud from throwing a LiveCD into my system and access the files on the hard drive and I believe I can achieve that with Truecrypt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### GNU Privacy Guard

As a long time user of both TrueCrypt and Symantec I cannot recommend both highly enough.

I have not had any issues with either.

I have also used [GPG](http://www.gnupg.org/) which is OpenSource and it works well.

And here is an [article from a google](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/five-apps/five-apps-for-disk-and-file-encryption-in-windows/#.) search which provides two other solutions I have not used.

Comment: I'd love to use Truecrypt but their documentation doesn't seem to recommend it's use for whole disk encryption of a SSD because of TRIM.

Symantec says they fully support SSDs but their price tag is a bit high.

GPG doesn't do whole disk encryption I don't believe

Comment: I know, you said so much in your question - hence I would go with Symantec.  But if you want opensource go with GNU.

Comment: So you are looking for a decryption password at boot time? In that case yes, GPG does not do what you want it to.

Comment: What I want is basically Truecrypts whole disk encryption. It encrypts the entire drive and at boot asks me for a password to unlock it.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that BitLocker can be run without needing a USB key. More information can be found [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6229/how-to-use-bitlocker-on-drives-without-tpm/), scroll down to "Use BitLocker on a Drive Without TPM."

Answer (score 0):

TrueCrypt works perfectly fine with SSD, I'm not sure where you got the idea that it does not.

There are more options, VeraCrypt (the new truecrypt) and DiskCryptor which is a bit faster than most for OS encryption